# CoreMotion how can I play music while user jumps up and down?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, accelerometer, devicemotion

I'm coding an iOS app in Swift, I need to play music while the user is jumping up and down (detected via coreMotion).

Playing the audio is fine, But I do not know how to trigger/stop the music using coreMotion.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Detect obstacle y position and on that basis you can push and play .(you can use device direction too if required) .

Comment: So sorry I forgot to thank you! Have a great 2017 :)